# Why proper ideals are non unital sub rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

In the definition of an ideal there is stability by multiplication by any element of the ring $$ri\in I\ \forall r\in R, i\in I$$

In particular we have the internal multiplication stability because $r\in I\subset R$.

In the sub-ring definition we only have stability by internal multiplication. $$s_1s_2\in S\ \forall s_1,s_2\in S $$

An ideal is a sub-ring, that I understand...
How come the ideals of a ring different from $R$ are precisely the sub-rings that don't contain $1_R$ ?

**Edit:**

It is not true that a non-unital sub-ring is necessarily an ideal. I misinterpreted a remark, there is a counter example in the comments. Sorry about that.

Comment: Well the ideal $(1)$ contains $1$, it's just the whole ring though.

Comment: Proper ideals. There is one ideal that does contain the $1$, and that is the whole ring.

Comment: Is this true? It's clear that if $1\in I$ then $I=R$ by the ``stability'' property, so non-trivial ideals cannot contain the identity. But it is not clear that all subrings that do not contain $1$ are ideals.

Comment: Sorry I meant proper ideals

Comment: An ideal is certainly a subring, and a _proper_ ideal cannot contain $1$. What makes you think the converse holds?

Comment: As a remark in my notes: "Proper ideals are subrings but not unital ones"

Comment: It's not true that the proper ideals are _precisely_ the subrings without $1_R$. For example, consider $2\mathbb Z+4i\mathbb Z\subseteq\mathbb Z[i]$ - it's a nonunital subring, but not an ideal.

Comment: Your notes are correct, and the adjective 'proper' is important. If $1\in I$, then for all $r\in R$ you must have $r=r\cdot 1\in I$. This implies that $I=R$.

Comment: @Wojowu That doesn't seem right. take $a+bi\in\mathbb{Z}[i]$ and $2z_1+4iz_2\in2\mathbb{Z}+4i\mathbb{Z}$ with $b=z_1=1$ and the imaginary part isn't a multiple of 4 so it's not an ideal

Comment: @StanislasHildebrandt Not sure what you are trying to show. I'm claiming this is a subring, not an ideal.

Comment: oh right! sorry.